# How to submit two mongoose find queries to the proper GET route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two separate app.get routes that render "/" and contain mongoose find{} methods, which relates to two mongodb collections. I then have corresponding post routes that redirect/post to "/" with the data I entered on the forms.

Depending on the form I use (devportals/new or writingportals/new) to submit my data, I would like it to use the correct app.get to find the data and then populate my index.ejs file to display the new entry.

When I submit my post, it always defaults to the devportal.find{} GET route at the top even though I submitted my update to mongodb through the writingportals form.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res){
devportal.find({}, function(err, newDevPortal){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.render("index",{newDevPortal: newDevPortal});
    }
});});

app.get("/", function (req, res){
writingportal.find({}, function(err, newWritingPortal){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.render("index",{newWritingPortal: newWritingPortal});
    }
 });
});


app.get("/portals/writingportals/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("portals/writingportals/new");
});

app.get("/portals/devportals/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("portals/devportals/new");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
var wpTitle = req.body.writingtitle;
var wpUrl = req.body.writingurl;
var wpImageUrl = req.body.writingimageurl;

writingportal.create({title: wpTitle, url: wpUrl, imageurl: wpImageUrl},     function(err, newWritingPortal){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
    });
    });

app.post("/", function(req, res){
var devTitle = req.body.writingtitle;
var devUrl = req.body.writingurl;
var devImageUrl = req.body.writingimageurl;

devportal.create({title: devTitle, url: devUrl, imageurl: devImageUrl}, function(err, newDevPortal){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is another way to do it, except declaring different endpoint for each request

Comment: There is no way for your code to know the difference between those endpoints... thats why the first one is always hit. Meaning you can't have two of the same endpoints defined with the same 'Type' of request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two separate app.get routes that render "/"

Your endpoints do not render "/", they get triggered based on the request uri, which in your case is "/".

Next, you cannot have two endpoints with the same route and same type of request, this is true with any web server. So in your case, you have two endpoints defined for GET requests to '/'. There is no way for your code to understand the difference between those two routes, so it will always hit the first one it finds.

Finally I'll add that for your solution, you most definitely will want unique endpoints because you are taking a template with a data model and sending back markup.... basically an endpoint for each page.

I will say that I'm not a huge fan of that approach. I think it makes life easier using a framework like react, then have every request to '/' return index.html with a reference to your react code... instead of the whole SSR deal.

However, for a lot of things, its simple to just use query parameters in the request. Here is an example where one endpoint is defined that will return all data from any collection through query parameters:

```
app.get('/api/collection', function(req, res) {
  var collection = req.query.collection;
  var _collection = db.collection(collection);
  _collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.send(docs);
  })
})
```

And then the request url would be `GET -> /api/collection?collection=NAME_OF_YOUR_COLLECTION`